# nginx upstream module is not working

Tags: nginx

[root@ansible3 nginx]# cd vhost.d/

[root@ansible3 vhost.d]# ls -rtlh

total 12K

-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 575 Apr  9 08:42 default.conf

-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 172 Apr  9 12:14 test.domainvhost.com.conf

-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 160 Apr  9 12:41 test.mynode.local.conf

[root@ansible3 vhost.d]# pwd
/etc/nginx/vhost.d

[root@ansible3 vhost.d]# cat test.mynode.local.conf

upstream  mynode {

```
 server localhost:9888;
```

}

server {

```
 server_name test.mynode.lcoal;

 location / {

             proxy_pass http://mynode;
```

}

}

[root@ansible3 vhost.d]#

static HTTP server running on 9888 port as below

root@ansible3 vhost.d]# elinks http://localhost:9888

test

so when i tried to run as below i am getting another output instead of test :( :(

[root@ansible3 vhost.d]# elinks http://test.mynode.local

```
                                                                        This is BHARATH WEB Server
```

```js
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {

    worker_connections 1024;

}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   15;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

   client_body_buffer_size 10k;
   client_header_buffer_size 1k;
   client_max_body_size 18m;
   large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;

   client_body_timeout 12;
   client_header_timeout 12;
   send_timeout 10;


    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/*.conf;

   # server {
   #     listen       80 default_server;
   #     listen       [::]:80 default_server;
   #     server_name  _;
   #     root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
   #     include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

   #     location / {
   #     }

   #     error_page 404 /404.html;
   #         location = /40x.html {
   #     }

   #     error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
   #         location = /50x.html {
   #     }
   # }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}
```

my /etc/hosts is as below

[root@ansible3 vhost.d]# cat /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 ansible3.bharath.com

::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6

localhost6.localdomain6

10.0.3.127 test.domainvhost.com

10.0.3.127 test.mynode.local mynode

[root@ansible3 vhost.d]#

and 9888 port is ran by my node JS static http server as below

```js
[root@ansible3 node]# cat server3.js
var http = require("http"),
    url = require("url"),
    path = require("path"),
    fs = require("fs")
    port = process.argv[2] || 9888,
    mimeTypes = {
  '.ico': 'image/x-icon',
    '.html': 'text/html',
    '.js': 'text/javascript',
    '.json': 'application/json',
    '.css': 'text/css',
    '.png': 'image/png',
    '.jpg': 'image/jpeg',
    '.wav': 'audio/wav',
    '.mp3': 'audio/mpeg',
    '.svg': 'image/svg+xml',
    '.pdf': 'application/pdf',
    '.doc': 'application/msword',
    '.eot': 'appliaction/vnd.ms-fontobject',
    '.ttf': 'aplication/font-sfnt'
  };



http.createServer(function(request, response) {

  var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname,
      filename = path.join(process.cwd(), uri);

  fs.exists(filename, function(exists) {
    if(!exists) {
      response.writeHead(404, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
      response.write("404 Not Found\n");
      response.end();
      return;
    }

    if (fs.statSync(filename).isDirectory())
      filename += '/index.html';

    fs.readFile(filename, "binary", function(err, file) {
      if(err) {
        response.writeHead(500, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write(err + "\n");
        response.end();
        return;
      }

      var mimeType = mimeTypes[filename.split('.').pop()];

      if (!mimeType) {
        mimeType = 'text/plain';
      }

      response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": mimeType });
      response.write(file, "binary");
      response.end();
    });
  });
}).listen(parseInt(port, 10));

console.log("Static file server running at\n  => http://localhost:" + port + "/\nCTRL + C to shutdown");
```

I Ran it as below

[root@ansible3 node]# node server3.js &

[4] 6345

[root@ansible3 node]# Static file server running at

=> http://localhost:9888/

CTRL + C to shutdown

echo "test" > index.html

Comment: static Node JS is running in the 9888

Comment: root@ansible3 vhost.d]# elinks http://localhost:9888                                                    
                                                                                                                                                           http://localhost:9888/
test .